# Set Freeform notification email dynamically

Tags: solspace-freeform

I have a modal box that pops up with a form anytime a person from a staff list is selected so that they can be contacted via the form without giving out their email address.

However, I'm having trouble figuring out how I can pass the staff members email address (which is in a field) to the freeform tag inside the modal without exposing their email address to the public.

I looked at the recipient parameter, but that wouldn't work since I don't want the user to have to select the recipient from a list in the modal again once they've selected a staff member to email.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the notify paramater to your {exp:freeform:form} opening tag.
Make sure the freeform tag is inside your staff fields loop and execute it like this:

{exp:freeform:form notify="{staff_email_field}" ...other parameters... }

Comment: Problem is that I the freeform is inside a modal window that gets called, so I need to somehow pass it the staff email address from the body of the site when the user clicks on that persons name.

Comment: I suppose you load the modal with an embed? You can pass extra data with your embed. For example, email="{staff_email_field}", in the modal template, you can get this variable with the following tag: {embed:email}